# How do I compute the surface of this solid?

Tags: 3d, surfaces

I want to compute the surface of the solid given by $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=z^2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
I thought about spherical coordinates, i.e.$$(x,y,z)=(r\cos\phi\sin\theta,r\sin\phi\sin\theta,r\cos\theta)$$
Then (1) would be equivalent to $$r^4=r^2\cos\theta\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$. I thought to take $r>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$ therefore (2) is equivalent to $$r=\pm \cos\theta$$. But can I then only define a parametrisation on $\theta, \phi$ of this solid?

I'm confused how to find it otherwise.

Could someone help me?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That surface is the union of the surfaces$$x^2+y^2+z^2=z\tag1$$and$$x^2+y^2+z^2=-z\tag2.$$But$$(1)\iff x^2+y^2+\left(z-\frac12\right)^2=\frac14$$and$$(2)\iff x^2+y^2+\left(z+\frac12\right)^2=\frac14.$$So, it's the union of two spheres.

Comment: Ah so you would first divide it into two spheres and then use spherical coordinates?

Comment: That depends upon what you want to do with this information. Besides, I explained how to answer your question using Cartesian coordinates because I saw how to do it using them. I suppose that the same answer can be obtained through spherical coordinates, but I did not try to do it.

Comment: You don’t need to use spherical coordinates at all. The two equations given should be immediately recognizable as spheres. I suppose using spherical coordinates might help you see this.

Comment: Ah okey so I‘ll try it thank you